# Is there is tool similar to ShiftIt on OS X?

Tags: gnome, rhel, window-manager, desktop

I'm looking for a keyboard controlled window sizing utility similar to ShiftIt on Mac OS X: https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt

Comment: The URL is kinda not too verbose to understand what you need actually.

Comment: @poige - maybe [this](http://lifehacker.com/5520734/shiftit-moves-windows-via-keyboard-is-like-aero-snap-for-your-mac) can help? I have been using [Breeze](http://www.autumnapps.com/breeze/) for OS X which is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want a feature that allows you to tile your windows like ShiftIt allows via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

As your question seems to be targeted at Gnome you might want to try [BlueTile](http://www.bluetile.org/) that seems to specifically target the Gnome-Desktop.

Apart from that I think the new Unity-Desktop from Canonical allows similar features via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and the NumPad keys (in 12.04 at least you can press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and see an overview over the available shortcuts).

And - even though I have never used it the [Grid-Plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid) for Compiz might also fit your needs.

Apart from that there are a ton of window managers that can do all the tiling for you, but they may require initial setup and be very different to use than the more common ones. Some examples in this camp include:

- [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/)
- [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/)
- [DWM](http://dwm.suckless.org/)

Comment: Thank you, these seem to be a great start for me to look at!

Answer (score 1):

GNOME already has some keyboard window manipulation available by default. Take a look at  https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts

Otherwise, you may want to try using another window manager with more window control options.

Answer (score 1):

So far nothing has really replaced ShiftIT.

I stumbled across [Shellshape](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/) which got me a little closer to what I wanted to achieve.

BlueTile -> Couldn't get it running on Debian.
Grid-Plugin -> Impossible to compile.

As another poster noted, it is perhaps better to investigate better window manager that has a more keyboard-centric touch.

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer (see mine comment), but it seems lots of X window newcomers do not know that Alt_MouseLeftBtn allows dragging windows around the screen and Alt_MouseRightBtn — resizing them (something that Mac OS X GUI <s>sucks for</s>lacks of) — so you don't need to take aim at hot window zones.

I usually prefer Fluxbox and it has [some key-binding for changing window geom](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts#Currently_Focused_Window_Commands) as well.